# Deep level xml parsing to csv using NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, xml, csv

I have a medium sized xml ~ 5mb that needs to be converted to csv.

Obviously wont go for reinventing the wheel, 
so a two layer approach - 
1> xml to json 
2> json to csv

My current code is :

```
const xml_obj = {}
const htt = require('http-status-code-node');
var fs = require('fs'); 
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var converter = require('json-2-csv'); 

xml_obj["convert"] = (req, res, next) => { 
  var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/directoryexport.xml', function (err, data) {   
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) { 
      console.log('Done'); 
      var callback = function (err, ycsv) {
        if (err) return console.log(err); 
        ///
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=testing.csv');
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        res.status(200).send(result);
        ///
      }
      var documents = [];      
      documents.push(result)
      converter.json2csv(documents, callback);      
    })
  });
} 
module.exports = xml_obj.convert
```

However the xml being nested gives a multi layered json which the yields a single string instead of a proper delimited csv..

[The current output CSV](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8u8XADz9kHeTjFZaEtQMm9vcE0)

[The Original xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8u8XADz9kHebWxfMnF3d1FyVFE)

[The XML structure](https://gist.github.com/crazysal/df23405476d1da26c1ac486cb0815ba0)

[The Json I get on converting xml](https://gist.github.com/crazysal/82caabc1177ae84ffe5902e88ff02f61)

Also as per the documentation of the json to csv converter 
if the input json is in a proper structure like :

```
[
    {
        Make: 'Nissan',
        Model: 'Murano',
        Year: '2013',
        Specifications: {
            Mileage: '7106',
            Trim: 'S AWD'
        }
    },
    {
        Make: 'BMW',
        Model: 'X5',
        Year: '2014',
        Specifications: {
            Mileage: '3287',
            Trim: 'M'
        }
    }
];
```

This yields a very nicely formatted csv like this : [Example Perfect CSV From JSON](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8u8XADz9kHeTjFZaEtQMm9vcE0)

Edit 1 :
The format I'm looking for is somewhat like, 
It's important to capture all parent organization and organizationalUnit details for each person node.
For example,

> organizationalUnit UUID "b3b05b77-a8a7-43ed-ab74-b7d898c60296" should
>   produce a CSV lines like:

```
"Mr Shayne Howard","Howard","Shayne","Mr","","Branch Manager","(02) 6121 5492","","Level 1, 12 Mort Street, Canberra, ACT, 2601","Shayne.Howard@employment.gov.au","","b43e0864-1b9a-40f0-8049-c90af5f9141c","","GPO Box 9880 CANBERRA ACT 2601 Australia",1392,"","Department of Employment","","1300 488 064","","","","http://www.employment.gov.au","GPO Box 9880, Canberra ACT 2601","EMPLOYMENT"
"Mr Luke de Jong","De Jong","Luke","Mr","","Branch Manager, General Counsel","(02) 6240 0909",""(02) 6123 5100"","","Luke.deJong@employment.gov.au","","58a503a8-ce8b-41c0-b690-b9f9efd98a89","","GPO Box 9880 CANBERRA ACT 2601",1393,"","Department of Employment","","1300 488 064","","","","http://www.employment.gov.au","GPO Box 9880, Canberra ACT 2601","EMPLOYMENT"
```

Edit 2 : 
Flattening out the json is a good idea, but its not capturing the entire data.
Using the **camaro nodejs module**  with the following template :

```
persons: ['//person', {
      root_organization_name: '../../../../name',
      main_organization_name: '../../../name',
      main_organization_website: '../../../website',
      fullName: 'fullName',
      familyName: 'familyName',
      firstName: 'firstName',
      personalTitle: 'personalTitle',
      title: 'title',
      person_phone: 'phone',
      person_location: 'location',
      person_fax: 'fax',
      otherRolesDN: 'otherRolesDN',
      person_mail: 'mail',
      informationPublicationScheme: '../informationPublicationScheme',
      publications: '../../publications',
      annualReport: '../../annualReport',
      mediaReleases: '../../mediaReleases',
      organizationUnit_1_name: '../../name',
      organizationUnit_1_description: '../../description',
      organizationUnit_1_location: '../../location',
      organizationUnit_1_phone: '../../phone',
      organizationUnit_1_fax: '../../fax',
      organizationUnit_1_website: '../../website',
      organizationUnit_2_name: '../name',
      organizationUnit_2_location: '../location',
      organizationUnit_2_phone: '../phone',
      organizationUnit_2_fax: '../fax',
      organizationUnit_2_website: '../website',
      occupantName: './role/occupantName',
      roleName: './role/roleName',
      occupantUUID: './role/occupantUUID',
      role_phone: './role/phone',
      role_fax: './role/fax',
      role_location: './role/location',
      role_mail: './role/ mail'
    }]
```

How could I also get the roles array. 
Also current csv gets some rows of data in wrong columns :

[Wrong csv after camaro](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8u8XADz9kHeOTUwT1RnVUVkR28) 
Any tips on how to make this work with my input.

Comment: Can you show what kind of output format are you looking for?

Comment: updated question with the same @TuanAnhTran

Comment: Try the code below to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the output of json structure is deep, if you want it to convert to csv properly, you would have to flatten it.

Seems like you only interest in deepest level. here's an example, if you want to add more data, feel free to add to the template

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const tocsv = require('json2csv')
const fs = require('fs')

const xml = fs.readFileSync('so.xml', 'utf-8')
const template = {
    persons: ['//person', {
        root_organization_name: '../../../../name',
        main_organization_name: '../../../name',
        main_organization_website: '../../../website',
        fullName: 'fullName',
        familyName: 'familyName',
        firstName: 'firstName',
        personalTitle: 'personalTitle',
        title: 'title',
        person_phone: 'phone',
        person_location: 'location',
        person_fax: 'fax',
        otherRolesDN: 'otherRolesDN',
        person_mail: 'mail',
        informationPublicationScheme: '../informationPublicationScheme',
        publications: '../../publications',
        annualReport: '../../annualReport',
        mediaReleases: '../../mediaReleases',
        organizationUnit_1_name: '../../name',
        organizationUnit_1_description: '../../description',
        organizationUnit_1_location: '../../location',
        organizationUnit_1_phone: '../../phone',
        organizationUnit_1_fax: '../../fax',
        organizationUnit_1_website: '../../website',
        organizationUnit_2_name: '../name',
        organizationUnit_2_location: '../location',
        organizationUnit_2_phone: '../phone',
        organizationUnit_2_fax: '../fax',
        organizationUnit_2_website: '../website',
        roles: ['../role', {
            occupantName: 'occupantName',
            roleName: 'roleName',
            occupantUUID: 'occupantUUID',
            role_phone: 'phone',
            role_fax: 'fax',
            role_location: 'location',
            role_mail: ' mail'
        }]
    }]
}

const result = transform(xml, template)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.roles, null, 4))
```

Example of output json (use json2csv to convert to csv if you want)

[image]

Comment: This is good, but this is only giving the deepest node of the json, can you tweak it to get all layers of the xml into a flat structure ?

Comment: in my example code, i gave an example of how to get upper level node's data. basically you can use `../` to go up 1 level. like this `organizationUnit: '../name'`

Comment: if you see the data from phone numbers is leaking into the column of names. and such indentation error Please check highlighted fields

Comment: @SaleemAhmed see updated answer with roles. I saw that roles is at the same level with person ?

Comment: @SaleemAhmed I don't see anything like that from my output. Can you check with the output i got here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5lnD5gfVd69emd5NjRpNWFyVUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: btw, roles is an array within person item. it would make the structure nested again (not flat)